# android linearlayout clip edges of sub linearlayout inside it

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have set the parent linear layout of a round corner effect. but the bottom rectangle corner of the embedded linear layout can't be clipped.

I have set the android:clipChildren="true" to the parent linear layout. and it still not work.

[image: Please check the image]